# How to get current day of the week and used it in scala template in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to get current day of the week by using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var now = new Date();
        var today = now.getDay();

        </script>
```

and want to used today date in if-else condition.How I can use this var in scala

Comment: you can't, that javascript code works on client side, play framework renders templates in server side, instead it get today using Scala at server side.

Comment: Thank you for that. I know to get today day in javascript but how to do this in scala and access that variable

Answer (score 1):

Following works,

```
@import java.time.LocalDateTime

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var date = "@Html(LocalDateTime.now().toString())";
        console.log(date);
    </script>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Joda DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/quickstart.html)

```
val dateTime = new DateTime();
println("Day:" + dateTime.getDayOfWeek);
```

To Pass DateTime object into template, write to top of template file;

```
@(datetime: DateTime)
```

For detailed documantation about ScalaTemplates -> https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/ScalaTemplates

You can declare it in template file;

```
@import org.joda.time.DateTime; val datetime = new DateTime();
```

Comment: Thanks Fatih, It will work fine but I want to declare a variable inside template and access that variable. which function I should used to get the current day.